# Push notification not coming when the app kills from the tab(Recent apps)?

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, gcmlistenerservice

I am searching for this from many days.but i could not get any solution.Notification is coming properly when the app in running or foreground state. but when the app kills from the recents apps tab(Task Manager) the notification would not arrive. i am so much frusted because of this problem. can anyone tell me what should i do for this.

This is my GcmBroadcastReceiver class :-

```
 public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
                {        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
                        GcmIntentService.class.getName());
                    startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
                    setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
                }
            }
```

This is GcmIntentService class by which i send the notification :-

```
 public class GcmIntentService extends IntentService {

        public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
        private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
        private final static String TAG = "GcmIntentService";
        private Context mContext;


        public GcmIntentService() {
            super("GcmIntentService");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
            Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
            Log.d(TAG, "Notification Data Json :" + extras.getString("message"));

            GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
            String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

            if (!extras.isEmpty()) {
                if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR
                        .equals(messageType)) {
                    sendNotification("Send error: " + extras.toString());

                } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED
                        .equals(messageType)) {
                    sendNotification("Deleted messages on server: " + extras.toString());

                } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE
                        .equals(messageType)) {
                    // This loop represents the service doing some work.
                    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                        Log.d(TAG, " Working... " + (i + 1) + "/5 @ "
                                + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(5000);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();

                        }
                    }
                    Log.i(TAG, "Completed work @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                    sendNotification(extras.getString("message"));
                }
            }        // Release the wake lock provided by the WakefulBroadcastReceiver.
            GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
        }     // Put the message into a notification and post it.


        private void sendNotification(String msg) {

            mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this
                    .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);


            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            intent.putExtra("KEY","aman");


            PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


            NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.sym_def_app_icon)
                    .setContentTitle("Telepoh")
                    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
                    .setContentText(msg)
                    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND | Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE);

            mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
            mBuilder.getNotification().flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
            mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);


            mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
        }

        private int getNotificationIcon() {
            boolean useWhiteIcon = (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP);
            return useWhiteIcon ? R.drawable.gcm : R.drawable.push_icon;
        }
    }
```

And This is my Manifest :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            package="package_name"
            android:versionCode="2"
            android:versionName="1.2">

            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

            <permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
            <permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

            <permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

            <permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
            <permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
            <permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

            <permission
                android:name="com.google.android.gcm.demo.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
                android:protectionLevel="signature" />

            <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gcm.demo.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

            <!-- This app has permission to register and receive data message. -->
            <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

            <application

                android:allowBackup="true"
                android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
                android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:largeHeap="true"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                android:supportsRtl="true"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
                tools:replace="android:icon">

                <meta-data
                    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
                    android:value="API_KEY" />

                <activity
                    android:name=".WelcomeActivity"
                    android:label="@string/app_name"
                    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
                    <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                    </intent-filter>
                </activity>
                <activity
                    android:name=".MainActivity"
                    android:label="@string/app_name"
                    android:launchMode="singleTop"
                    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
                <activity
                    android:name=".LoginActivity"
                    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
                <activity
                    android:name=".RegisterActivity"
                    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
                <activity android:name=".ForgetPasswordActivity" />


                <activity android:name="pacahe_name.controller.GalleryUtil" />

                <activity android:name="nl.changer.polypicker.ImagePickerActivity" />

                <receiver
                    android:name="package_name.GCM.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
                    android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
                    <intent-filter>

                        <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
                        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />

                        <category android:name=package_name" />
                    </intent-filter>
                </receiver>


                <service android:name="package_name.GCM.GcmIntentService" />


                <activity
                    android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
                    android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

                <meta-data
                    android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
                    android:value="@string/fb_id" />

                <meta-data
                    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
                    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
            </application>
        </manifest>
```

My problem is push notification working fine when the app in the run state and in the foreground state. But when app clean from the recents apps(Tab) then the notification is not coming.I tried package restarted but it does not working.If anyone know what i am doing wrong then please tell me.

Comment: Show the push payload you're sending

Comment: @TimCastelijns I don't know about the push payload.and i don't sending in my application.can you please tell me. what is this and what it does.

Comment: How are you sending push to device?

Comment: @TimCastelijns by the help of the notification manager.please see my code.

Comment: I mean the one that you send with GCM

Comment: @TimCastelijns i am sending the registration id with the gcm.

Comment: and what else? "notification" and/or "data" ?

Comment: @TimCastelijns i am passing some data. notification is working fine when the app in running or foreground state.but my problwm is when the app kills from the recent apps then notification don't arrive.please tell me any trick or idea. because i am so much frusted regarding this problem.

Comment: ..Can you show exactly what you are sending?

Comment: @TimCastelijns i am sending the message with the gcm.    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        Log.d(TAG, "Notification Data Json :" + extras.getString("message"));

        GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
        String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

Comment: @TimCastelijns Please see my GcmIntentService class i am sending the data in the onHandleIntent() method. please see it. you understand automatically what i am sending with the gcm.

Comment: I don't understand at all. The code you show is **receiving** the message. What I want to see is what exactly you are sending in the message from the **server** to the **device**

Comment: @TimCastelijns I am sending the message from the server to device like "user has requested to join your activity username".

Comment: All of it. The entire payload. All the stuff you put in the request that you send to google, not just 1 string.

Comment: @TimCastelijns if it is the problem. then when app is in running state and foreground state how can the notification arrive ??

Comment: I have an answer, but I have to verify if it is the right answer. To do that, I need you to show me what I have been asking for for 2 hours, but you won't. I'm not going to waste more time on this, good luck finding someone else.

Comment: @TimCastelijns by the way i am already sending the all the stuff i am puting in the request to the google.